# Testing if a program in assembly is working correctly

Tags: assembly, x86, return, output

I am very new to assembly, and I'm trying to build a very simple program for x86 that puts into EAX the values:

> (Nothing?) if EBX can be divided by 2^n with n>3
>
> 1 if EBX can be divided by 2^3 -> 8
>
> 2 if EBX can be divided by 2^2 -> 4
>
> 3 if EBX can be divided by 2^1 -> 2
>
> 0 if EBX is an odd number

So I've built this program and tested it out, everything runs fine, but I have no idea how to see if it actually does what I want it to do. I couldn't find any way to output a registry's current value, and the vast knowledge of internet could only provide me with partial answers that didn't take me very far.

One main concern for me is that I'm not sure if the ret statement returns to the _main function, or just "breaks" the execution. The latter is what I want. So is there a way for me to check if my program works right?

```
section .text
    global _main

_main:
    MOV EAX, EBX
    MOV ECX, 16
    DIV ECX
    CMP DX, 0    ;Op=word (1,0,0,0,0), AX := DX:AX/Op, DX -> rest
    JE end0      ;If number%16 == 0
    MOV EAX, EBX
    MOV ECX, 8
    DIV ECX
    CMP DX, 0    ;Op=word (1,0,0,0), AX := DX:AX/Op, DX -> rest
    JE end8      ;If number%8 == 0
    MOV EAX, EBX
    MOV ECX, 4
    DIV ECX
    CMP DX, 0    ;Op=word (1,0,0), AX := DX:AX/Op, DX -> rest
    JE end4      ;If number%4 == 0
    MOV EAX, EBX
    MOV ECX, 2
    DIV ECX
    CMP DX, 0    ;Op=word (1,0), AX := DX:AX/Op, DX -> rest
    JE end2      ;If number%2 == 0
    JMP end1     ;

end8:
    MOV EAX, 3
    ret

end4:
    MOV EAX, 2
    ret

end2:
    MOV EAX, 1
    ret

end1:
    MOV EAX, 0
    ret

end0:
    ret
```

Comment: After you run the program in a terminal the return code or exit status will be the value of `EAX` when the program returned from main, if you then type (on windows) `echo %errorlevel%` or (on linux) `echo $?` it will display that return code in the terminal.

Comment: I am sorry those commands don't work on my debugger. "No symbol "echo" in current context." it says. I tried with the dollar syntax as well but it doesn't seem to work with that either, since it says "> $errorlevel
 $2 = void"

Comment: @locust Those commands are not meant for a debugger sorry, i was just giving you a way to check your programs return value after running it, that's why i didn't make this an answer, the commands are meant for a terminal, you run the `echo` commands after you run your program in  the same terminal and they will show you your programs return code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a debugger to single step your code and examine registers and memory at every step.

As to your question about `ret`: it is the counterpart to `call`, roughly speaking it will continue after the most recent `call`. (This is a simplified view.) Note that you use simple conditional jumps such as `je end0` so the `ret` in `end0` will not return to that location. Rather, it will exit your `_main` and continue at whoever called it, which was presumably the C startup code. Effectively it exits your `_main`. As far as I can tell, this is exactly what you want.

PS: You are using `DIV` wrong, it only works by accident. It implicitly uses `EDX` as the high 32 words of the dividend, so you should always zero it for 32 bit unsigned division. Even your comment says that, although that describes the operation of the 16 bit version.

Also note that to check divisibility by powers of 2, one normally uses bitwise operations, not divisions.

Comment: Thank you for the swift answer! I did try to use a debugger, however I'm using NASM as an IDE and thus, the debugger provided with it doesn't give me any output if there is no error encountered during the execution. Perhaps I am doing something wrong. 
I did not understand your PS. What does zeroing the EDX registry mean? Should I not use the AX and DX registries and use their extended (32 bit) versions instead? And by bitwise operations do you mean shifting? I am not certain I understand their concept very well, so I went with a safe way.